# tensorflow cudart64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

При попытке запустить любой код на Керасе или Тенсорфлоу выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел решения на английском стаке и там рекомендовали скачать cuda версии 10.1 или выше. Я скачал и 10.1 - не работало, и 11.1(последняя) тоже не сработало. Также скачал tf-nightly(был такой совет) - не помогло. Всегда вылетает ошибка `Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'` иногда вместо cudart64_101.dll пишет cudart64_110.dll, сам файл этот есть в папке с cuda и путь к папке правильный. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu есть список cuDNN и CUDA.
Если нужная другая CUDA надо собирать самому или тут брать https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

Comment: Прямо сейчас у меня скачан cuDNN 7.6 и CUDA 10.1, но ошибка не исчезает

Comment: Стоит указать версию TF и откуда установлена

Comment: TF 2.3.1 , установлена с помощью pip install